# sortBy attribute not parsed correctly in Composite Component that extends p:dataTable

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, datatable, composite-component

I'm writing an app using Primefaces, and I need to create a decent amount of datatables. Since the configuration of those datatables are almost identical, I decided to create a Composite Component for those. I created a file in the web folder, `/resources/composite/myDatatable.xhtml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite">

    <cc:interface>
        <cc:attribute name="value" type="java.lang.Object" />
        <cc:attribute name="sortBy" type="javax.el.ValueExpression" />
        <cc:attribute name="emptyMessage" type="java.lang.String" />
    </cc:interface>

    <cc:implementation>

        <p:dataTable
            value="#{cc.attrs.value}"
            var="tableRow"
            emptyMessage="#{cc.attrs.emptyMessage}"
            lazy="true"
            rows="15"
            sortBy="#{cc.attrs.sortBy}"
            sortOrder="ascending"
            paginator="true"
            paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"
            paginatorPosition="bottom"
            paginatorTemplate="#{rmsg.datatable_pagination_template}" 
            currentPageReportTemplate="#{rmsg.datatable_pagination_current_page}" 
            pageLinks="5" 
            styleClass="my-datatable">

            <cc:insertChildren />

        </p:dataTable>

    </cc:implementation>

</html>
```

Now I'm trying to use it like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                template="/WEB-INF/templates/main_template.xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
                xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"
                xmlns:my="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/composite">

    <ui:define name="content">
        <div class="ui-fluid">
            <h:form>
                <p:panelGrid layout="grid" columns="1" styleClass="my-panelgrid">
                    <my:myDatatable
                        value="#{componentBean.model}"
                        sortBy="#{tableRow.name}"
                        emptyMessage="#{rmsg.datatable_empty_components}">

                        <p:column headerText="#{rmsg.header_components_name}" sortBy="#{tableRow.name}">
                            <h:outputText value="#{tableRow.name}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="#{rmsg.header_components_friendly_name}">
                            <h:outputText value="#{tableRow.friendlyName}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="#{rmsg.header_components_dependson}">
                            <h:outputText value="#{tableRow.dependsOn.name}" rendered="#{tableRow.dependsOn != null}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="#{rmsg.header_components_type}">
                            <h:outputText value="#{tableRow.type}" />
                        </p:column>

                    </my:myDatatable>
                </p:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </div>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

My problem is the following: When the LazyDataModel is loading it's data, it tries to sort on the String `attrs.sortBy`, instead of the value I've given it `#{tableRow.name}`.

How can I solve this? Is my interpretation of Composite Components wrong?

Comment: What is your PF version?  If I remember correctly, this field is not one that interprets the data as EL, but parses it by itself (strips the #{ and }, drops the first part of the 'field' (cc in your case) and uses the rest as a field on the element of the var. So you could put `#{blablabla.attrs.sortBy}` in there and it works the same

Comment: @Kukeltje I'm using PF 6.1, but you think there is no way I can get it to work?

Comment: No idea... never wrapped a component like this with a field that behaves this way. But I know of the OptimusFaces project that does something similar. I could check there, but you should to, it is a very, very interesting project by the famous, fabulous, fantastic BalusC and partners

Comment: Can you try the `sortField` attribute instead of `sortBy`? I checked the [DataTableRenderer.java](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/datatable/DataTableRenderer.java), noticed some peculiarities but sortField might work

Comment: @Kukeltje When I use sortField, it does render, but an empty string is passed trough to the loading method. So no sorting.

Comment: How did you pass/populate it? Looking at the code, it should just take a string (`<my:myDatatable
                        value="#{componentBean.model}"
                        sortBy="name"` if I looked correctly... (or even "bla.name")...